# Python KafkaConsumer SSL Parameters

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka

I am working on Python script to consume messages from Kafka API using KafkaConsumer library.

My requirement is to connect to Kafka using SSL security Protocol. The admin has shared certificate in .Pem format which has Root, Intermediate and certificate all together in one file.This certificate is provided by out internal Certificate Authority and is required to be presented while connecting to Kafka.

I have below questions.

1. Can I manually extract the Root, Intermediate and Certificate and save them in .Pem format using notepad? If this is possible then do I need to store these files at any specific location or I can refer them in script with direct path?
2. Do I need to provide ssl_keyfile argument too? If yes then Private or Public key?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should use `openssl` CLI to extract data (if you need it), not a text editor

Comment: Thank you. May I know which key I need to provide to ssl_keyfile? Public or private

Comment: Usually, in this context, that refers to the private key.

Comment: Thank you sauerburger and One rocketeer. Can you help me with Openssl command.  I found on Google that  it is used to generate a new certificate. I already have a certificate but just need to separate Root and client certificates in different files. Can you share Openssl command which can do this?